# How do I make a function print out a certain amount of Random numbers through the command line? C

Tags: c, random, command, argv, argc

How do I pass an arguement and print that amount of numbers in my program? So far I have found out that if I change count to a lower number than argc, the amount of numbers increases. However,  I want it to print x amount of numbers on whatever I type in the command line like 10.
Thanks

```
int random( int limi, int lims);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int count;
srand(time(NULL));
int p;
int input;
int i = 0;


if (argc > 1)
{
  for ( count = 1; count < argc; count++)
{

 p = random(-10000,10000);

  printf(" %d\n",p );


}
}
else
  {
    printf("The command had no other arguments.\n");
  }

return 0;
}

int random( int limi, int lims )
{
          return ( rand() % (lims - limi) - lims);
 }
```

Comment: have you actually tried compiling this?  after prepending #include statements for stdio.h, stdlib.h, and time.h there were still several warnings.  Please post code the cleanly compiles, (unless your having problems obtaining a clean compile.)  Compile with all warnings enabled to have the compiler tell you what is wrong with the code.  Fix the warnings before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to your application are passed in as an array of strings in argv[]. To convert the first argument to an integer, parse it using atoi(), strtol() or sscanf():

```
if (argc > 1)
{
    int amount = atoi(argv[1]);
    for ( count = 1; count < amount; count++)
    {
         p = random(-10000,10000);

         printf(" %d\n",p );

    }
}
```

The arguments start from argv[1]. argv[0] will be the name of your program.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out when I get on my laptop! Ill report back if I have any more problems! Thank you so much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the `random()` function

```
return ( rand() % (lims - limi) - lims);
```

In the first place `% (lims - limi)` will produce a range too short by 1. And after the modulus operation, you should add the lower limit, not subtract the upper one. In your question, the limits were -10000 and 10000 so it made no difference, but if you had called it as, say, `random(10,20)` you would see the error.

In the `main()` function, `argc` gives the number of arguments. The first (`argv[0]`) is usually the name of the executable, so you need to check if there is more than 1 argument and then convert the string to a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random( int limi, int lims )
{
    return ( rand() % (lims - limi + 1) + limi);
    //return ( rand() % (lims - limi) - lims);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int count, p, input;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    if (argc > 1)                                   // if argument supplied
    {
        if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &input) == 1)     // check valid input
        {
            for (count=0; count<input; count++)
            {
                p = random (-10000, 10000);
                printf("%d\n", p);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had no idea about the random error function! Thanks for specifying the errors and explaining how it caused them. And the argv[1] is going to be my argument so if I enter 10, it is going to loop that X amount of times and print out that X amount of numbers correct? Anyways thank you for your help, I'll report back if I have any further trouble as well. Thanks!